# How do I not display api errors in laravel?

Tags: laravel

For example, I have a notification and when I call this notification, it should send a message to the user via SMS

```
public function toKavenegar($notifiable)
{
    return (new KavenegarMessage("welcome to app"))->from('10004346');
}
```

This code has no problem and sends the message.
But I may have entered the ‍`api key` incorrectly and the service provider will return the message that the `api key` is incorrect.
Now how to prevent the problem that if the request is not made, no message will be displayed and the program will continue to work

Comment: Wrap with try catch (similarly what @hamidreza showed you) but in controller where notification is issued (where `toKavenegar ` method is called). In catch block after error log (for example) you can set redirect to where ever you need. Or maybe with setting flash session variable if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try block

```php
    public function toKavenegar($notifiable)
    {
         try{ 
             return (new KavenegarMessage("welcome to app"))->from('10004346');
            }catch($e){
              report($e);
          }
    }
```

in above example if there is a error in sending sms it will save it in log files but it won't throw

Comment: ‍I tried this but still the error shows the `api key` is not correct
`try` Only errors show our program